# Write to internet explorer debug console from asp.net mvc 4 controller

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to know how to write debug messages to internet explorer debug console from my asp.net mvc 4 controller. I have doing below but it is not working. When I publish my app in the default web site and I launch it, no messages are printed out to the internet explorer console.

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception raised from the controller: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can try out [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). though it won't write to ie debug console, but it can write to text files/database and many other media. just have a look.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.Write*` is your local output window, not IE. So, if you want to write to IE (and assuming `console.*` is what you mean *and* is supported...) you'd need something like:

```
@{
  Message = /* ??? source ??? */;
}
<script>console.log(@Message)</script>
```

However, that means that the `ex.Message` now needs to be passed to the view (albeit view model, `ViewBag`, etc.).

A better solution, however, may be to look in to something like either Elmah (for logging and tracking) or Glimpse (to give you "client side" debug information).

Comment: Yes, from the mvc view I can use razor and scripting but I need to do it from the controller (C# code, no possibility to use razor and scripting there).

Comment: @user1624552: then it's not possible. The controller is on the server and won't get to IE.

Comment: The call to the controller is done through an ajax jquery call so is it possible to return an http status with a custom error message such as ex.message to the jquery call? and then from jquery code to popup an alert with this custom error (I only need this for debugging).

Comment: @user1624552: Should have mentioned this is an AJAX call earlier on. Just return something like `return Json(new { error = ex.Message })` from the controller, then check `if(data.error){ console.log(data.error); }` in your AJAX callback. Likewise, you could return a plain string and just output it as well.

Comment: I have done it but it is not working. After getting that error in my ajax call I try to parse to json but it says it is not a json object. Also the error sent by the controller is not visible in the ajax call. See another of my threads. There I describe the issue more detailed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614418/returning-custom-error-from-mvc-controller-to-jquery-ajax-call